# Google Cloud Compute : GCP Virtual Machine Creation : Quota 'NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 in region europe-west1

Tags: virtual-machine, gcloud

I've registered recently to GCP (with upgraded profile), and I'm trying to create a VM but I keep getting the same error.

Here is the code I use in the console :

```
gcloud beta compute instances create my_vm_name \
    --boot-disk-size=200 \
    --tags http-server,https-server \
    --scopes=cloud-platform,storage-full \
    --custom-cpu 8 --custom-memory 100 --custom-extensions \
    --zone europe-west1-b \
    --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=2 \
    --image-family ubuntu-1604-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud  \
    --maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure
```

And I get the following messages :

```
WARNING: Some requests generated warnings:
 - Disk size: '200 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'. You might need to resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not support automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd for details.
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 1.0 in region europe-west1.
```

I've already searched and here is what I've done :

1) Increase the NVIDIA_K80_GPUS Quota from 0 to 2 for the region europe-west1.

2) Increase the GPUS_ALL_REGIONS Quota from 0 to 2.

For each request I received an email from Google confirming that the request was approved.

But I still get this message...

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Quota is still not increased. Do the following to verify it. Go to Cloud Console> IAM & Admin> Quotas

In the Quotas section, click on Metric drop down click None, then search for K80, then select NVIDIA K80 GPUs. This will show your quota for for K80 GPUs in all the regions. I would recommend using the region where you see the quota available. You could also raise a request here using the Edit Quotas button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You may be right, I see now that I made a request of quota increase for "committed NVIDIA K80 GPUs" and not "NVIDIA K80 GPUs". Maybe this explains the error ? I'll make a new request now